# Can't use a Dictionary as an argument to a BuildProcessTemplate in VS2010?

Tags: c#

I am trying to customize my build process template in VS2010. I have added an argument called "temp", of type "Dictionary < String, String >". I want the default value to be:
  "new Dictionary < String, String > ()"

When I enter the default value, VS complains:
  "Compiler error encountered process expression [...] '.' expected"

I've tried a few different variations on the default value (semicolon at the end; no semicolon at the end; String vs string; etc.), but haven't gotten it to work. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

I changed the default value to:

```
new Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

and that appears to work. However, I still cannot initialize the dictionary like so:

```
new Dictionary(Of String, String) {   {"cat", "dog"} }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Turns out the "from" syntax works:

```
New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"cat", "dog"}}
```